# JDBC oracle update statements in java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Can someone tell me why this fails at the `ps.excuteUpdate` statement? It seems to work and changes the data in the database but it fails at the execute statement which won't let it execute the other two ps1 and ps2 statements.

```
    buyStock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                BuyStock();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });





public void BuyStock() throws SQLException, IOException{
 Connection conn = null;
 PreparedStatement ps = null;
 PreparedStatement ps1 = null;
 PreparedStatement ps2 = null;
 int i = 0;
 String username = UserLoginInfo.userEmail;
 int bank = 75000;
 String string1= "goog";
 int shares = 25;

 conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();

 if (i == 0) {

    ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE L1_Standings SET BANK = ? WHERE EMAIL = '" + username + "'");
    ps1 = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE L1_Stocks SET TICKER_SYMBOL = ? WHERE EMAIL = '" + username + "'");
    ps2 = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE L1_Stocks SET NUM_SHARES = ? WHERE EMAIL = '" + username + "'");

    ps.setInt(1, bank);
    ps1.setString(1, string1);
    ps2.setInt(1, shares);

    ps.executeUpdate();
    ps1.executeUpdate();
    ps2.executeUpdate();

    ps.close();
    ps1.close();
    ps2.close();

} else {
    System.out.println("False");
}
```

Comment: Can you put a try/catch block and post the resulting SQLException that this code is thrown?

Comment: Why are you using string concatenation? Don't.

Comment: Does you code compile? If you did not add `throws ` your exceptions to method signature, your code will not compile. Either add `throws` or use try/catch

Comment: What does "fail" mean?  Please show the errors.